# Replacing TRRS Jack with TRS

Tags: audio, wiring, headphones

I've a handset which i was using with my galaxy ace 4 then changed to experia z1 
Anyway the handset butom was raising volume instead of pausing and then the jack was giving static and then it was done
So i googled and founs that i can fix it 
Searched in my city for TRRS jack and didn't found 
So I got a TRS Jack drom radioshack and then tried to connect 
Basically i can't wire what where all working and even tried putting ground to the highest one then putting the red and green wores together on one of the 3 conductors and it worked so maybw ican use the mic as well?
If not where to wire what?
I mean there's red green black and copper
Red green is the headphones and black is mic and the forth is the ground
There's 2 conductor and both have same height

What i noticed is i must put one of the red or green on the highest then the other on any and it would work

Edit (01);

I've a samsung hand set using it on experia phone.
Its jack.got messed up (like always).
Went to radioshack didn't find a 3.5mm jack with four conductors so i got a 3 conductors one and decided that i don'tneed mic
As you can see on top the 3 conductor one got 2 pins of the samw height so i don't know what's ring and what's tip
The second one is the old jack which is 4 conductors (left right mic ground)

The third is the wires which is green red black copper

Tried to connect it and it seems to work if i connect one of the (red/green) to the highest pin and the other to any one of the lower ones without even connecting ground

Googled again found a reddit post about a guy who want to do the same and cancel the mic and he messed up with colors 
But i googled and found an adapter trrs to trs so if that works i think i can make the mic work as far i understand that you can connect one (red/green) with the copper and connect the other one and connect the black (mic) to the third
I wanted to try but i'm afraid to make a mistake that harms the device so asked for help
Hope this is more understandable
The Pic; https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff0pY.jpg
[image]

TL;dr: 
1. How to use a TRS Jack instead of TRRS of the handset

2. Can i make the mic work?
3. Which is the tip and which is the sleve and which is the ring as there's two of the same height
   Thanka guys

Edit (2): 
So i connected as following 
Sleeve: black warpes around copper (common/ground and mix)
Ring: red wire (right audio)
Tip: green (left audio)

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Instead of the standard for 4 conductors which ia from sleeve to tip is mic ground right left

I don't know if this will harm the phone or the handset or not really.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SE!  This looks like the beginnings of a good question, but there are two things that would make it worth the experts' time:  1)  Break up the wall of text into something a bit more readable.  We get lost easily.  2)  Add a schematic of what you're trying to do.  Most of us think graphically and spend considerable effort to translate words into pictures, so if you can just give us those pictures it would be that much easier to understand you.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i'm using android so it's kinda bad i'll supply images but drive isn't working so i'll find another server and edit

Comment: Yeah, the Android app is more of a "stay connected" sort of thing and not particularly useful for a complete question or answer.

Comment: I don'thave access to a Computer. Try playing hearthstone on an mobile and not miss swiping.

Comment: I edited the poat dude

Comment: Given your link, I made the picture inline in case the link dies.  As for the app and the PC access, all I can say is, I agree.  And it's annoying.  The app is good for basic monitoring and commenting, but still needs a lot of work for the full functionality.  Can you trick your phone into using the website instead of the app?

Comment: Yeah i guess I can request a Computer access from the browser and most sites have a computer view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no official standard, so this is not guaranteed, but the one that works for me is:

- T: Left Speaker
- R: Right Speaker
- R: Ground
- S: Mic

In that order.  The most common variation that I see documented is to swap Mic and Ground, but I haven't seen that in my limited sample size.  I think I've heard of another one that puts the Mic on the Tip, but don't quote me on that.

I would make some reliable but easily removed connections per the above and test it.  See if you get all the right signals in the right places, adjust as necessary, and make it permanent when you get it right.

The one thing to be careful about in most cases is accidentally connecting two outputs together, which you don't have to worry about here because you're throwing away the mic.

---

If you want to salvage the mic, you'll have to settle for mono headphones instead of stereo, and I have no idea what the pinout is for that.

I will say, however, that you shouldn't just connect Left and Right together.  That makes two outputs fighting each other, and you may not like the result.  You could throw away Left or Right and keep the other, but that would ruin some music.  Or you could put a resistor in series with each one and then tie the resistors together, but that can make certain headphones sound weird.  A powered buffer/amplifier would fix that, but then you'd need one of those.

Comment: Thanka but my new jack is trs and i can't seem to know which is tip and which is ring

Comment: @MohamedAmr The two rings get combined into one for a total of 3 connections instead of 4.  So it's Tip/Ring/Sleeve instead of Tip/Ring/Ring/Sleeve.  As for the signal names, slide the S: up in my description to replace the first R: and then delete the Mic line entirely.  That's the standard for 3-pin stereo headphones.

Comment: http://pinoutsguide.com/HeadsetsHeadphones/samsung_i9100_headset_pinout.shtml

Comment: @MohamedAmr Yep, that matches mine for the 4-pin version.

Comment: Look at the new jack on the picture you can see the tip and ring the same height how to differentiate

Comment: @MohamedAmr I'm going by the order that they list them.

Comment: @MohamedAmr Do you mean the solder connections?

Comment: Yeah sorry i didn't know the name

Comment: @MohamedAmr Ah! Okay, now I get it. For those, you can look closely at the stackup and understand that it's all concentric, so the furthest away on one end will also be furthest away on the other.  Or you can use a continuity checker.

Comment: So tip is green

Comment: So tip is green and ring is ground and red and the sleeve is mic?

Comment: @MohamedAmr I can't verify which color is what.  There's no standard for that either.  You'll have to test it on your own.  The only potential issue is driving the mic like a speaker, but you're throwing that away anyway, right?  Otherwise, you can't hurt it by the wrong connection.

Comment: If possible i want to connect the mic

Comment: I'm testing now but whatever

Comment: @MohamedAmr See my notes at the bottom of this answer about salvaging the mic.

Comment: Can you make it simplier?

Comment: So the mic is now working

Comment: @MohamedAmr Great!  Keep in mind, though, that this is an engineering problem.  There are as many solutions as there are engineers...several times over.  Each one comes with advantages and disadvantages, some of which I mentioned in the answer.  Only you know what advantages you need and what disadvantages you don't care about.

Comment: Hmmm don?t know why they didn't get screws

Comment: Googling to find out what color is what but can you tell me what could go wrong?

Comment: @MohamedAmr Without a standard and without external visibility, nothing says they can't replace an empty reel with a full one of whatever they had on hand and continue making the same part number.  It'd be worth trying Google's answer first, but don't be surprised if it doesn't match what you have.

Comment: I put the mic in tip and it worked still train and erroring the others but there's no screws to make sure.... Just to make sure if we said red right green left mic black ground copper so i would go green tip ring red and copper black sleeve

Comment: This couldn't damage my phone right?

Comment: @MohamedAmr Any decent phone should be pretty tough at the headphone jack, just because the designers have no idea what's going to end up getting stuck in there.  But as soon as I say that, yours will probably turn out to be the one that doesn't protect itself.  :-P  Anyway, I'd be more concerned about the headphones.  Most of those are considered cheap enough to omit the self protection.

Comment: Omg mic is working on tip and sleeve and ring

Comment: So with left in sleeve and right and ground on ring and mic on tip it's working

Comment: What if i canceled ground?

Comment: @MohamedAmr That seems weird, but without an official standard I guess it *might* be right.  Without an explicit ground, it'll use the speakers as ground, which will echo the speakers back into the mic.  If your headset has buttons, the impedance of the speakers *might* mess with them too because that's how it knows which button you wanted: each button puts a different resistance between mic and ground.

Comment: My handset got a buttom which is for pause. Anyway then left with tip ans right with ground at ring and mic at sleeve

Comment: They didn't suplly screws don't know why.

Comment: @MohamedAmr Why do you need screws?

Comment: Don't i use screws to instal wires? I dont have any tomorrow i'll go to a shop and try to make the technician do it and ask him and i'll till you

Comment: @MohamedAmr Soldering is better.  Screws usually leave "whiskers" unless you're really careful, which can slowly wave around and eventually find something that they shouldn't.  Industrial screw terminals are designed to completely enclose the stripped part so that doesn't happen, but they're also huge, unlike what you have here.  Besides, your holes aren't threaded so you'd need a nut on the back, which takes up even more room.  A good solder joint would be little bigger than the tab and the wire and probably stronger against pulling too.

Comment: Yeah i guess i just got this freaking jack for the shield

Comment: Like what this guy did i founs him on instructable.   https://youtu.be/vMAm0P04aGA

Comment: @MohamedAmr  Yeah, he got a different jack.  Yours is designed for solder.

Comment: *Plug*, actually.  It plugs a hole.  Not sure where the term *jack* comes from.

Comment: http://imgur.com/tLaDuF0

Comment: @MohamedAmr "Screw-on *housing*", not terminals.  The plastic cover screws on, but the wires need solder.

Comment: So what happened is i went to the electric shop and asked if there's jacks with 4 conductors (if i said trrs i don't know he would know what is that) and he even said there's no such thing and was being an asswhole, so i said YOLO connected ground and mix to sleeve and red to ring and green to tip (mic and ground then right audio then left) and tested it and it worked so i'm going to solder them now ( i hope to do it right, i'll google) also googled to see what is the potential damage and JACK (Nothing) http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35343/can-we-connect-a-normal-earphone-headphone

Comment: Done friend although i messed up the sleeve solder so i warped it around the sleeve "thing" and lifted up the plastic thing alittle so it won't touch the outer body

Comment: Anyway i did as following

Comment: Tip was green  ( left audio) ring is red (right audio) sleeve is copper and black (mic, warped them around each other) and it's working okay now with mic but unfortunately i can't use the handset button but whocares, thanks man i'm quite good with computers if you want somwthing xD and i'm a great googler

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/cZj20u6h.jpg. Pleas eadd this to the question

Answer (score 0):

My other answer was based on an incorrect understanding of the problem, but it does have some good information so I'll leave it.

---

To determine which ear to solder to for each contact, you can look closely at the stackup and understand that it's all concentric.  This means that the layers have to "peel off" in order from outside to inside on both ends, so you can just count the insulator layers between tabs.

Here's a different design that shows this better:
[image]
From here: http://ch00ftech.com/2011/12/27/the-ch00f-o-scope/

Or you could use a continuity checker.